# correct syntax for writing a copy command inside procedure in PGAdmin tool

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have a requirement where i need to copy the records from Table A to CSV file with copy command via procedures.
Directly using this command returns success:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM <Table_Name>)
   TO '<CSV file location>'
   DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

But when I use below command it gives syntax error:

```
syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

```
BEGIN
COPY (SELECT * FROM <Table_Name>) TO '<CSV File location>' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
END;
```

Also Below procedures didn't help .

```
create or replace procedure copy_table as
declare 
sql varchar;
begin
        sql = 'COPY (SELECT * FROM personsaddrs limit 10) TO ''/tmp/Shivangi_File2.csv'' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER';
        perform sql;
end;

BEGIN
copy_table;
END;
```

This also returns an error

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up PL/pgSQL's `BEGIN`, which starts a block, and SQL's `BEGIN`, which is short for `START TRANSACTION` and starts a transaction.

You forgot the semicolon after `BEGIN`. But a transaction that contains only a single statement need not be explicit; simply omit  it.

In your PL/pgSQL code you forgot to double the quotes in

```
DELIMITER ','
```

Comment: I tried by putting double quotes as mentioned above but still no luck. 
This command works
COPY (SELECT * FROM <Table_Name>) TO '<CSV_File_Location>' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
But when i place this under BEGIN and END , it throws syntax error at or near SELECT .

BEGIN
COPY (SELECT * FROM <Table_Name>) TO '<CSV_File_Location>' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
END;

Comment: Did you read my answer concerning `BEGIN`? I could have been clearer about the quotes: you have to use two single quotes rather than a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You created a `PROCEDURE`, you need to use it with a `CALL`;  `CALL copy_table;`. If it where a `FUNCTION` then you would do: `SELECT copy_table;`.

Comment: When i am using CALL copy_table;  then also getting a syntax error which states that - 

ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: CALL copy_table
                       ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at end of input
SQL state: 42601
Character: 16